# Desactivate notifications when post to facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i'm developping an app for facebook page allows switching covers by itself.
The point is, notifications are sending every time cover is set. Is there a way to desactivate notifications by PHP Sdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, via the `no_feed_story = true` parameter.

One caveat though: Facebook now sends notifications to users who subscribe to a Page's notifications every single time now. I have been having this issue for almost 2 months!
This was not the case before, Facebook is not fixing it though.

I had opened a bug before, but they decided to close it yesterday since they believed not enough Users/developers had been impacted...

Please subscribe to the new bug here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/214524952029507 and complain!